# A browser event fired before users navigate to other URL

Tags: javascript, html

For HTML5-compatible browsers, do we have a event fired before users navigate to other URL?

My requirement is to popup a confirmed dialog if users navigate to other pages via clicking links or changing location.href.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)